# JLabel does not display properly when using the command line "java -jar myApp.jar"

Tags: java, swing

My code:

```
var jf = new JFrame("test");
jf.setSize(640, 480);
jf.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug"));
jf.add(new JLabel("123"), "wrap");
jf.add(new JLabel("<html><p>123</p></html>"));
jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
jf.setVisible(true);
```

When i run it in eclipse:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5zXH.png)
The height of the jlabel is 16, and both look the same。

But when I package it as a jar and run it from the command line:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jilQI.png)
The height of the jlabel become 18, and after using html tags there is an extra padding above。

I programmed in windows and this problem exists on both win10 and win11.

This is beyond my knowledge, i wanna know why and how to make the frame of command line run exactly the same as inside the IDE?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an exact detailed description, with all the intermediate steps, on how you build your JAR file. Also add a [mcve] to your question, which can be tested by others. And include the java versions you are using when you compile, build and run your java application.

Comment: A `JFrame` has a default font, `Dialog`.  You don't specify the font for the HTML, so Windows uses a slightly different default font than Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I tried to set the font at the beginning of the program by UIManager.put(key, fontResource), but the problem still exists.